# Unique decipherability of infinite regular language

Tags: regular-languages, automata, coding-theory

Can we design an algorithm to test if a infinite regular language is a code?

We have the S-P algorithm to determinate if a finite language is a code. But how about the infinite part of regular languages?
If we have a regex which describes our set of words, then is it possible to modify the S-P algorithm to work on an infinite set without creating Pattern Matching Machines? If it helps, let the regex use only '* | ()' as special symbols.

I thought about making an algorithm which would work based on a PMM, but it isn't as trivial as the S-P algorithm for finite sets, checking the suffixes of strings with matching prefix. The algorithm would be creating a PMM from the regex and traversing it for the search of suffixes etc. like in the S-P algorithm.

Comment: For those who are wondering what S-P is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

McCloskey gave such an algorithm in his paper [An $O(n^2)$ Time Algorithm for Deciding
Whether a Regular Language is a Code](https://www.cs.scranton.edu/%7Emccloske/publications/code_alg_header_mar2011.pdf). Given an NFA on $n$ states, his algorithm runs in time $O(n^2)$. Since a regular expression of length $n$ can be converted to an NFA with $O(n)$ states in linear time, McCloskey's algorithms runs in quadratic time even when given a regular expression as an input.